# CSS transitions delaying

Tags: html, css

I discovered CSS transitions this morning on StackOverflow (I'm a newer web developer, mind you.) and I was trying to re-vamp one of the sites that I'm currently building, by adding a nice fade-in effect on my link color changes & my div hover effects on my page.  The effect works very nicely, but I'm noticing a weird delay that hopefully someone can help me out with.

**The Problem**:  When I have nested elements that should both receive a transition, they aren't happening simultaneously, they are waiting for the parent transition to stop and then the child transition begins.

**HTML**: Note - This is razor text normally, but I have provided the raw HTML without any C# syntax

```
                  <div class="image-caption">
                    <h1>Heading</h1>
                    <p>Hello world, I am an example paragraph.</p>
                    <a href="#" target="_self">
                      <div class="image-link">
                           Link Text!
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
```

**CSS / LESS**:
I was looking for a way to quickly convert all div & link effects on my site to fade smoothly. I found the code below on StackOverflow and noticed that if I didn't include the :hover & :focus selectors, that all of the links on the page would transition from a pretty large size down to their normal size when the page loaded which looked funny.

```
div, a, i{
   &:hover, &:focus {
        -o-transition: .5s;
        -moz-transition: .5s;
        -webkit-transition: .5s;
        transition: .5s;
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the actual styling of the caption.

```
.image-caption {
 //irrelevant CSS removed here
   a {
   &:hover, &:focus{
   color: rgba(19, 56, 97, 1.0);

     .image-link{
      border-color: rgba(19, 56, 97, 1.0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should only apply the fade-in on the parent div.  Anything nested within will fade at the same time/pace.

Comment: You also may want to look into jQuery and jQuery UI.  These give lots of dynamic transition options which can be executed easily by DOM triggers, etc.

Comment: You don't need `-o-` and `-moz-` prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by removing the DIV declaration on the global DIV / I / A transition rule, and then creating a couple of mixins to handle independent transition cases like this.

**New Global Rule & Mixins**:

```
a, i {
    &:hover, &:focus {
        -o-transition: .5s;
        -moz-transition: .5s;
        -webkit-transition: .5s;
        transition: .5s;
    }
}

.no-fade() {
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}

.make-fade() {
    -o-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

**New CSS / LESS to fade nests at the same time**: - (for clarification, .image-link is a DIV)

```
a {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    color: #FEFEFE;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;

    &:hover, &:focus {
        color: rgba(19, 56, 97, 1.0);
        .no-fade();

        .image-link {
            .make-fade();
            border-color: rgba(19, 56, 97, 1.0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use transition property directly on selectors (not on hover and focus states)

```
div, a, i {
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

Comment: As I listed in the original post, this is not an option because all the links on the page show the transition as they resize to their specified heights when the page first loads and it looks bad.

Comment: That's not really an option.  It's a bootstrap 3 web app and I've got at least 10 LESS files being compiled into a minified CSS.  I am just providing the relevant details of my issue

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help with my weird issue, but I was able to address the issue myself which I have posted.